# All combination of score for a given score list

Tags: algorithm, recursion, combinations

I am trying to get all the combination of points for a given score using

> recurssion

Here is my code snippet

```
public class CombinationForGivenScore {


        public static void FindCombination(int score[],int x,int ans[],int index){
            if(x == 0){
                for(int i = 0;i<index;i++){
                    System.out.print(ans[i]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            else if(x>0){
                for(int i =0;i<score.length;i++){
                        x = x -score[i];
                        ans[index] = score[i];
                        index++;
                        FindCombination(score, x, ans, index);
                }

            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
            int score[] = {1,2,3}; // valid score 
            int ans[] = new int[100]; // just a large array to store the combination
            int index = 0; // index for the ans array
            int x = 3; // total score
            FindCombination(score, x, ans, index);
        }

    }
```

I am expecting this result

> x = 3 output 111 12 21 3

what i am getting is

> 111 12

According to my understanding the loop will create a recursive call for each number in score array. 
But its not working that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these statements:

```
x = x -score[i];
// ...
index++;
```

you change the local variables `x` and `index`, which means that they will have thr wrong values in subsequent passes through the loop. But you want to change them only in the next instance of recursion, i.e in the function that you are going to call:

```
for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    ans[index] = score[i];
    FindCombination(score, x - score[i], ans, index + 1);
}
```